# PHP pre-selected drop-down

Tags: javascript, php, html, postgresql, session-variables

```
while($row_list=pg_fetch_assoc($list)){
    echo '<option' if(isset($_SESSION['hoopSelect'])){ echo 'selected="'$_SESSION['hoopSelect']'"'; } ' value='. $row_list['username'] . '>' . $row_list['username'] . '</option>';}
```

I want to have my while loop continue working while if $_SESSION['hoopSelect'] is set to 'small' for example, reloading the page it will pre-select the option. 
It runs perfectly without `if(isset($_SESSION['hoopSelect'])){ echo 'selected="'$_SESSION['hoopSelect']'"'; } '`

I get an error page 500 when i add this, i wonder if i am placing it in the wrong location, or if i have strcutured it incorrectly, thanks for any input.

Comment: You need to use concatenation. For example, `echo '<option' . if(isset($_SES...` and `'; } ' . value='` You seem to be using it properly in many places, but those stick out.

Comment: Hi E. Could you please format your code properly? It would help us identify a potential problem more easily. Also, a 500 status code means an internal server error, which most likely means a syntax error in your code.

Comment: Hi Jay, I believe you are right, i've played around with concatenation on this line of code for hours, to confirm are you telling me echo '<option' . is incorrect? I appreciate the guidance.